Auto-linking React Native modules for target BiTop

I have this problem when trying to do a pod install, has it happened to anyone? It is a react native project
I thank you in advance for any questions or solutions or contributions.
I'm on the lookout for anything, I hope you can help me, greetings

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
